# how to parse encrypted data in oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I want to transmit the information in encrypted form. I have JSON. In this jsonI store 3 variables. I want to encrypt them and pass them in one line. But then I want to decrypt this string and get 3 variables from this string.

My json :

```html
"{"device": "114a947e-c261-c837-bf40-8f721f019000","device_licensen": "3231231-c8c4-bf47-6860-8c601f019000","date": "02/10/2022"}"
```

I was thinking of some other way but I can't think of anything. My goal in one oracle-apex is to encrypt 3 variables in one line. Then pass this information to the second oracle-apex. And already on it to decipher this term, and to write down variables which I deciphered in the necessary table! I will be grateful for the help.

Comment: What problem are are you trying to solve with this encryption? Ideally your data is *already* encrypted in transit using HTTPS / TLS, so what does this level of additional encryption add to your architecture? Who are you protecting the data from?

Comment: @pmdba I may not have fully explained that this encrypted string will be transmitted in encrypted form, but you can still see it through the apex of the oracle. And I want to copy it (encrypted variables) from one apex oracle and paste it into a form in another apex oracle project. After that, this cipher should be decrypted and written in the desired table

Comment: So who are you protecting the data from? The user? What is the point of the encryption? What you're asking about would be pretty complex to set up: you'd need to manage encryption keys between the two databases and write a custom function to handle the encryption/decryption process. Secure key management is *not* trivial, either. From a security/complexity perspective you'd be better off transmitting the data directly from one database to the other (not through the UI) using a REST call.

Comment: Or set up a database link and not use JSON at all. Also, the title appears to be misleading as you do not want to hash the data as this is a one-way function that is not reversible.

Comment: @pmdba I'm developing a device licensing policy. In my program, I create a user license, which specifies the expiration date and device. This data is transmitted via the REST API, and licenses are automatically updated in the client. But it happens that the server on which the apex oracle is deployed is in the client's internal network. And it is not possible to transfer the license through API REST. To do this, I want to give him a coded license, which he would insert into a special form. And with this process, this encrypted message will be decrypted and written to the desired table.

Comment: @pmdba  Do you understand what I want?

Comment: @pmdba that is, I want to pass the following message to the client "'9B9D3FEF1EB5255AA1EC8C10FF2290DF0991909D43C84EDCCADC6D3EF2FAB4375FF384A2422A108E0902A1BD9AADE88A0317A682CE552916DDEF He would insert it in the desired shape. And in this form, this message would be deciphered and written down.

Comment: yes, but not sure why you need to encrypt the data in question. You would have to place the decryption keys and algorithms *in* the customer database and then manage them somehow, so you're really making your solution much more complicated and not solving the original problem, since the client would also have access to the keys *and* the decrypted data. Sounds like the client application needs to *pull* the keys from your license server rather than have them pushed. Reverse your REST API call. Even then, the client will have access to the data; you can't change that.

Comment: An alternative would be to keep the license on the server and send the user an otherwise meaningless token that has a one-to-one correspondence to the license and then when you want to check that the license is valid the user can send back a one-way hash of the concatenation of a unique identifier for the user and their license token and then you hash the same data on the server and compare.

Comment: @pmdba the client does not have access to the workspace, only to the apex, ie he will not be able to see the decryption keys, or somehow edit them. And rest in a closed network does not work.

Comment: @MT0 Thank you, but you understand that from a closed network there is no access to my API, ie there is no connection.

Comment: Who manages the database, if not the client? If there's no network connectivity, then you really don't have many options, as you wouldn't be able to manage encryption keys either. hard-coding keys into a database function is a *bad* idea.

Comment: @pmdba I manage, I am given access, through a special program. The user has access only to the application itself. But he can't control anything. That is, my goal is to pass 3 variables in that drain.

Comment: Now I'm really confused: if you're managing the server and have complete control of their environment through some kind of bastion host(?), why does the customer need a separate license key at all? What purpose does it serve? Or why couldn't you enter the key yourself? Why make the customer do it?

Comment: Also, most license keys are themselves some kind of encrypted/hashed data that wouldn't require *additional* encryption to protect.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242001/discussion-between-andrii-havrylyak-and-pmdba).

Comment: @pmdba Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Comment: @pmdba can you help me with my question?

Comment: What does your question have to do with "hashing" (in your title)? Clearly you want "encryption" (since you say several times you want to be able to decrypt). I'll edit your title - change it back if there really was a good reason to say "hashing".

Comment: @mathguy Yes, you corrected correctly! I was wrong

Comment: @pmdba can you help me with my question? I will be very grateful if you help me

Comment: I can't see a good way to implement what you're talking about, and I confess I don't understand the requirement. If you can't manage the client environment then there's no way to safely manage encryption keys to do what you want. If you *are* able to manage the environment and any encryption keys, then why not also manage the license key to begin with? Why isn't the license key sufficiently protected by definition that it requires additional encryption? As I asked originally, what *problem* with license key deployment is your encryption trying to solve? What's the risk of not encrypting it?